# Suppress Case Transfer Email Via Apex

Tags: case

Has anyone successfully been able to suppress the case transfer email when case ownership is transferred via apex?

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kwkkAAA

That form post indicates to me that this is not possible, at least via configuration of support settings. Is this possible via Apex to suppress this email?

On a side note, where in the pine woods does this email template live? I am tempted to delete it to see if that prevents the email from going out.

Comment: You can find email templates within "Unified Public Email Templates"  @ **Setup--> Communication Templates --> email templates**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [How to stop "Case Notification Email" from salesforce?](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h1kEAAQ)

> In Setup > Administer > Manage Users > Queues, find the queue in which you would like to stop all automated emails.
>   Uncheck "Send Email to Members" AND put a fake email adress in "Queue Email" field. For instance "fake@e.mail" or what your imagination may find. Since the queue is unable to stop sending email, the trick is to insert a false email adress. The email server will receive the sending order, but will be unable to execute it.
>   If you leave this field blank, then all the members of the queue will still receive emails, despite unchecking "Send Email to Members". That's why you must fill it in with any text under the form of an email address.
>   Knowledge base article here ([How to stop email notification to Queue members?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=How-to-stop-email-notification-to-Queue-members-1327108336049&language=en_US&type=1))

To do this via Apex you want the sObject with the [00G](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#00G) keyprefix. Oddly, while this is a Queue in the UI, it is a [Group](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_group.htm) at the API level.

You can SOQL the group records in Apex and modify the `Email` and `DoesSendEmailToMembers` fields as required.